# How to redirect to dashboard after login in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a login form in with `onSubmit` property pointing to the following function:

```
function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(email);
    login(email, password);
}
```

The login function used above takes email and password from the form and is is defined in another file like this:

```
export const login = async (email, password) => {
  const config = {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
  };
  const body = JSON.stringify({ email, password });
  const res = await axios.post(
    "http://localhost:5000/userauth/login",
    body,
    config
  );
  console.log("token: ", res.data);
  return res.data;
};
```

Now I want to redirect the user to a dashboard component after a successful login. How do I approach this? I read that private route is needed for this. But I cannot understand how to use it in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you want to navigate to `/dashboad` page after successful login

put `this.props.history.push('/dashboard')` inside your function of login submit

```
function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(email);
    login(email, password);
     this.props.history.push('/dashboard')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go with a more robust approach. 
You will probably want the user to be redirected to the URL he was intended to and not necessary your default one.

So I would add this code on your login function:

```js
const { history, redirectTarget } = redirect;
history.push(redirectTarget);
```

and will pass the following data from your Login Component/Container:

```js
let redirectTarget = 'defaultURL';
try {
  redirectTarget = this.props.location.state.from/pathname;
}
catch (err) {
  redirectTarget = 'defaultURL';
}
this.props.loginRequestAction(
  { username, password },
  { history: this.props.history, redirectTarget }
);
```